# Sorting on date after querying on multiple specific keys

Tags: couchdb

Document structure:

```
{
  "Type":"post"
  "LastModified":"2010-11-01 21:55",
  "CategoryID":3,
  "ID":12
}
```

Having a bunch of different post docs in different categories is great. But I can't seem to figure out how to make a view which returns the documents ordered by date, when selecting the ones in, e.g., category 3 and 5. The categories are not known, the limit query should work still.

I've tried different approaches to the view but nothing comes close to achieving the desired result.

In SQL it could probably be done by something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE document.CategoryID in (3,5) ORDER BY document.LastModified DESC;
```

I could just query a view like this the required number of times, manually sorting and paging the data:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.CategoryID, doc.ID);
}
```

So does anyone know if it's possible to avoid doing that and just have couchdb be a bit smarter?

Comment: Have you tried the couchdb mailing list? I think they might suggest pulling all the records for a given set of categories into a seperate database which has a view keyed by 'LastModified'

Comment: yeah, that's just too complicated. I think I'll have to use to calls, one to get the posts key with [category, date] and then selecting the necessary categories with a POST to the view, getting just the doc.id's and then doing a manual sort and then another request for the actual documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible solutions.

1. Emit both `CategoryID` and `LastModified` in the map function.

   ```
   function(doc) {
       emit([doc.CategoryID, doc.LastModified], null);
   }
   ```

   Now you can query the view for `?startkey=[3]&endkey=[3, {}]` to get all the docs with `CategoryID=3` sorted by `LastModified`. To get docs for multiple CategoryIDs, you need to merge the sorted results.
2. Use [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) to build the index. couchdb-lucene can handle complex queries.

Comment: I went with something on the lines of your first suggestion.